# How to add "Ubuntu Font Family" to my site using CSS?

Tags: css

How do I add the Ubuntu Font Family in CSS editor for my site? Here's what I have for my font and header already, but  don't want the current font I have, I want Ubuntu Font.

```
/* ##### Common Styles ##### */

body {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "times new roman", times, roman, serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

acronym, .titleTip {
  font-style: italic;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

or

```
/* ##### Header ##### */

#header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.headerTitle {
  font-size: 200%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0.5ex 0;
}

.headerTitle a {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: "trebuchet ms", verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subHeader {
  display: none;
}


/* ##### Side Bars ##### */

#side-bar {
  display: none;
}


/* ##### Main Copy ##### */

#main-copy {
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main-copy h1 {
  font-family: "trebuchet ms", verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 120%;
  margin: 2ex 0 1ex 0;
  padding: 0;
```

Where do I add Ubuntu Font Family? And did I insert the wrong code to help you, help me?

Answer (score 31):

## Importing the font

First, you have to make sure, your site has that font in case the average user who visits your site doesn't have it.

### Option 1 - Import from external provider

You can import the whole font file and settings from an external font host like Google Fonts. Just add this code to your HTML to import it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&subset=Latin">
```

### Option 2 - Store it in your server

You can download then upload the font files to your server, then import them via `@font-face` in your CSS. In this example the place of your font file will be `http://example.com/fonts/ubuntu.woff`.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Ubuntu'), url(http://example.com/fonts/ubuntu.woff) format('woff');
}
```

## Using the font

You have to specify where do you want to use that font. Just add `Ubuntu` to your `font-family` list:

```css
body {
    font-family: Ubuntu, "times new roman", times, roman, serif;
}
```

This example code will make the Ubuntu font the default font for every text in your entire web page unless it is overriden by a more specific CSS rule.

Comment: Thanks! And how do I import fonts?

Comment: Ah, I see now. It doesn't really change, but I should talk to the host developers. Thanks.

Comment: @totymedli made a couple headings for you.. think that clarifies the question a little better.

Comment: link working perfectly but when i downloading and using in my site its not working will you please send me proper link where i can download and use it. Thanks

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas The googleapis link is a link for the CSS file, you can download the fonts themselves from the links in that file.

Comment: link not working for me can you share link for me ?

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas The [link to the CSS](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,bold&subset=Latin) and [to the font file](http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/ubuntu/v7/BxfrwvhZBmVnDwajjdTQeH-_kf6ByYO6CLYdB4HQE-Y.woff2) works perfectly, you do something wrong.

Comment: i want to download font and use in website. your link is working perfectly but i want to download and then want to use in site. i just want to know where can i download this font and how to use in site because i try allot but fail.. then i used your flow and it works but i still want to know why downloading font not working. hope you get my point. thanks

Comment: @MuddasirAbbas Just save the file I linked. Place it in your webserver and change the url in the font-face to your font url in your server. I can't help more, comments are not for this, if you have problems please ask a new question.